# Making a column to help aggregation in r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to construct a new column for R dataframe that would help in aggregation.

First, I have some vectors:

```
vector1 <- c("ITEM11","ITEM12","ITEM13")
vector2 <- c("ITEM21","ITEM22","ITEM32")
```

and dataframe DF which has column VAR with the items included in the vectors. Now I want to make new column AGGVAR:

```
DF$AGGVAR[DF$VAR %in% vector1] <- "vector1"
```

This is manageable with small amount of vectors but I want to make it neater for more vectors. I made list

```
vectorList <- ls(pattern = "^vector")
```

and my obviously naive attempt was

```
for(i in regList){DF$AGGVAR[DF$VAR %in i] <- i}
```

What is still needed to make this work?

EDIT: My problem was actually bit more hairy than I first presented. The vectors don't actually have neat numerical suffixes, e.g.:

```
vectorGHI <- c("ITEM11","ITEM12","ITEM13")
vectorJKL <- c("ITEM21","ITEM22","ITEM32")
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
vector1 <- c("ITEM11","ITEM12","ITEM13")
vector2 <- c("ITEM21","ITEM22","ITEM32")

d <- data.frame(var=c(vector1, vector2))
L <- mget(ls(patt='^vector'))
d$aggvar <- paste0('vector', sapply(d$var, grep, L))

d
#      var  aggvar
# 1 ITEM11 vector1
# 2 ITEM12 vector1
# 3 ITEM13 vector1
# 4 ITEM21 vector2
# 5 ITEM22 vector2
# 6 ITEM32 vector2
```

An alternative, which might have better performance:

```
lookup <- cbind(unlist(L), 
                c(mapply(rep, names(L), sapply(L, length))))

d$aggvar <- lookup[match(d$var, lookup[, 1]), 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified answer based on jbaums' suggestion to make this complete:

```
namesVectors <- ls(pattern = "^vector")
vectorList <- mget(namesVectors)
# Getting rid of auxiliary prefix
namesVectors <- substring(namesVectors, 7)

DF$AGGVAR <- sapply(DF$VAR, grep, vectorList)
for(i in length(namesVectors)) {DF$AGGVAR[DF$AGGVAR == i] <- namesVectors[i]}
```